# Открытие файла по щелчку на ссылку HTML

Tags: html

Как сделать, чтобы по щелчку на ссылку файл не только загружался, но и открывался в ОС? Желательно, чтобы сразу открывался, без загрузки.

```
<a href="files/1.ods">Вакансии</a>
```

Comment: если на своей машине, то только написанием плагина.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это невозможно сделать из-за настроек безопасности всех основных браузеров.